# Only the first related type of entity found instead of both

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, h2

So I have this problem, which is described in the image below

[image]

We use entities in Java for each table, all names are checked and correct.
For testing, we use an emulated database in XML format.
The entities use NamedQueries where a parameter can be inserted from the related Repository.

I'm thinking there's something conceptually wrong with my image design but I don't know what...

I also removed the lazy fetching even though the JOIN FETCH in HQL overrides them, to no avail.

It doesn't matter if I start the query from the linking entity or the license/request type, it always returns an empty list.

The HQL queries are (not exactly their names):

```
@NamedQuery(name="Permission.findByLicenseType", query = 
    "SELECT p FROM Permission p " +
    "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.linkingEntity link " +
    "LEFT JOIN FETCH link.licenseType lt " +
    "WHERE lt.code = :code")

@NamedQuery(name="Permission.findByRequestType", query = 
    "SELECT p FROM Permission p " +
    "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.linkingEntity link " +
    "LEFT JOIN FETCH link.requestType rt " +
    "WHERE rt.code = :code")
```

Comment: actually it looks like Hibernate sees this as a ManyToMany (which it started out as) where it only supports one type at either end